# Foreground service when user unchecks show notification

Tags: android, foregroundnotification

I'm using a foreground service in one of my app. Android 4.1 or above users can uncheck my app's notifications. Does this make my foreground service a background.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I am not trying to hide the notification in my app, but I am wondering if once a user un-checks "show notifications", if the app is still run as a foreground service (i.e. cannot really be killed by the system).

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.3 this was addressed with a system notification instead of app notification. Here is the [blog post](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/MTinJWdNL8t).

Comment: Please check the answer in this site. Its contradicting.

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/how-to-hide-status-bar-notification-icons

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. madhu is providing a notification. And yes, your Service is still a foreground Service. The unchecking of notifications is just a visibility thing and does not affect your ability bein a foreground service.

Comment: @deekay: Is there any reference for this?? I tried to get it, but could not. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Changed the answer. This is considered as broken behaviour and you will see a system notification since android 4.3.

Comment: @Tautvydas U are misunderstanding my question again and again. I'm showing the notification. But, user can uncheck my notification through settings. At this time, will my service still be considered as foreground???

Comment: Yes it will be. As too many application are relying on this feature. As described in the google plus post and [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/07/30/notifications-foreground-services-android-4p3.html).